# chrome developer tools, what's loading?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome

When I open a site the loading spinner keeps spinning in the favicon area and I see the 'waiting for site.com' message.

It seems to me like the site has already fully loaded, but evidently not.

How do I check what's still loading?

I'm happy to use Firebug as well if it's easier to see there.

Edit:

Network tab doesn't indicate anything is still loading.

Edit: is there any way to filter network tab to see what's still incomplete vs already completed requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use developer tools (Network tab) for this analysis.

Answer (score 0):

To check what's still loading, first open the Developer Tools (press F12) and switch to the Network tab.  Then load the site; you'll see all the requests the page makes.  From there, you'll be able to see which aren't yet done.